# Build a universal sbt file in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Hello i have a sbt file like this:

```
    name := "Myexample"

    version := "1.0"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4",
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.4"
    )
```

I want to fix a universal sbt file. If other computer has other scala version or spark version can i make a sbt file dynamic, not declaring my own scalaVersion at all, but declaring in every computer their own scalaversion or apache spark version??

Comment: _"has other scala version or spark version "_ stroke me since the purpose of this `build.sbt` and any other build configuration file is to avoid any system dependencies and pull all required from outside. With that said, I'm not sure I understand your question really.

Comment: Requirement seem to be a bit strange. The purpose of the dependency management tools like sbt or maven are to help the other way. And why would you run two different versions at the same time unless they are for different projects or applications. In that case sbt also has to be different with the required versions.